# Power Quality Measurement & Reporting Standards

Tags: three-phase, power-factor-correction, standard, harmonics, power-quality

I'm analyzing power quality in low and medium voltage facilities (50/60Hz; 0.48 - 69 kV; factories, campuses, etc.) while trying to apply existing standards wherever possible. In addition to demand metering the main PQ metrics I'm tracking are:

- Voltage levels
- Harmonics
- Phase imbalance
- Power factor

While it's easy-ish to find a number that IEEE or IEC uses as a standard, it's harder to find how that number is specifically calculated. For instance, 0.8-0.85 is often cited as a minimum acceptable power factor for C&I facilities, but what value does that minimum apply to? The mean over an hour? The minimum instantaneous measurement that month? For most PQ measurements this specification is very hard to find.

I did find [this detailed description](https://www.neo-messtechnik.com/en/power-quality-explained-chapter-3-ieee-519-harmonics) of applying IEEE 519 to harmonics data which was great. They recommend testing 95th/99th percentile values daily and weekly. Are there detailed processes like that for the other metrics listed above? If not, any recommendations on what makes most sense to track for C&I facilities?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely located in the US so these IEC/EN Std might not fully apply be helpful to you.

Very quickly,

Have you checked Annex B "Power quality measurement – Guidance for applications" of IEC 61000-4-30:2015+AMD1:2021?

B.1.3.2 Power frequency
Measurement interval: 1-week minimum assessment period.

B.1.3.3 Magnitude of the supply voltage
Measurement interval: 1-week minimum assessment period.

B.1.3.4 Flicker
Measurement interval: 1-week minimum assessment period.

B.1.3.5 Voltage dips/swells
Measurement interval: 1-year minimum assessment period.

B.1.3.6 Voltage interruptions
Measurement interval: 1-year minimum assessment period.

Otherwise EN50160 Voltage characteristics of electricity supplied by public
distribution networks, will have what you are looking for.

A UK DSO called UKPN will likely have more helpful info but you need to create an account with them to access their documents. More specifically they will detail to some degree how(/when/what) power quality studies are conducted. Again country specific UK Guidelines will apply like ENA P28 (Voltage fluctuations), P29 (unbalance), G5 (Harmonics) Look for:

eds-08-0132 planning guidance for disturbing loads,

eds-08-1901 guidance for the connection of customers disturbing loads,

eds-08-5055 power quality assessment process for mode 4-electric vehicle charging points,

Another useful resource with a fair amount of free reports/guides is the EPRI (US gov research) website. For example but not limited to:
PQ encyclopedia (Some chapters are free),
Power Quality for Transmission and Distribution: Harmonics Design and Analytics Guidebook,
Understanding the Causes and Impacts of Voltage Unbalance

Finally as you mentioned the 95% percentile value of 10min averages is typically used for most of these parameters with 1 week integer multiples being the minimum measurement period.

Hope you find something new and useful from this.

Good luck!